# My login function can´t verify my changed password

Tags: php, database

i put a forgotpassword system on my web and it´s working. The password is changed on the database. But then i can´t login. The password_verify can not verify the new password. What i´m missing?

This is my forgotpass.php

```
 //Password submiting
        case 3:
            //we are submitting a new password (only for encrypted)
            if ($_POST['userID'] == '' || $_POST['key'] == '') header("location: login.php");
            if (strcmp($_POST['pw0'],$_POST['pw1']) != 0 || trim($_POST['pw0']) == '')
            {
                $error = true;
                $show = 'recoverForm';
            } else {
                $error = false;
                $show = 'recoverSuccess';
                updateUserPassword($_POST['userID'],$_POST['pw0'],$_POST['key']);
            }
        break;
    }
}
       elseif (isset($_GET['a']) && $_GET['a'] == 'recover' && $_GET['email'] != "") {
    $show = 'invalidKey';
    $result = checkEmailKey($_GET['email'],urldecode(base64_decode($_GET['u'])));

case 'recoverForm': ?>
    <h2>Password Recovery</h2>
    <p>Welcome back, <?= getUserName($securityUser=='' ? $_POST['userID'] : $securityUser); ?>.</p>
    <p>In the fields below, enter your new password.</p>
    <?php if ($error == true) { ?><span class="error">The new passwords must match and must not be empty.</span><?php } ?>
    <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        <div class="fieldGroup"><label for="pw0">New Password</label><div class="field"><input type="password" class="input" name="pw0" id="pw0" value="" maxlength="20"></div></div>
        <div class="fieldGroup"><label for="pw1">Confirm Password</label><div class="field"><input type="password" class="input" name="pw1" id="pw1" value="" maxlength="20"></div></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="subStep" value="3" />
        <input type="hidden" name="userID" value="<?= $securityUser=='' ? $_POST['userID'] : $securityUser; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?= $_GET['email']=='' ? $_POST['key'] : $_GET['email']; ?>" />
        <div class="fieldGroup"><input type="submit" value="Submit" style="margin-left: 150px;" /></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </form>
```

And this is my functions.php (With the function to the login and to the recovery pass)

```
function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
    // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password 
        FROM users
       WHERE email = ?
        LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password);
        $stmt->fetch();

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
            // from too many login attempts 

            if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
                // Account is locked 
                // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
                return false;
            } else {
                // Check if the password in the database matches
                // the password the user submitted. We are using
                // the password_verify function to avoid timing attacks.
                if (password_verify($password, $db_password)) {
                    // Password is correct!
                    // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", 
                                                                "", 
                                                                $username);
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', 
                              $db_password . $user_browser);
                    // Login successful.
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Password is not correct
                    // We record this attempt in the database
                    $now = time();
                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time)
                                    VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // No user exists.
            return false;
        }
    }
}




function login_check($mysqli) {
    // Check if all session variables are set

    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'], 
                        $_SESSION['username'],
                        $_SESSION['email'],
                        $_SESSION['login_string'])) {

        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $login_string = $_SESSION['login_string'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $email= $_SESSION['email'];

        // Get the user-agent string of the user.
        $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password 
                                      FROM users
                                      WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1")) {
            // Bind "$user_id" to parameter. 
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
            $stmt->execute();   // Execute the prepared query.
            $stmt->store_result();

            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                // If the user exists get variables from result.
                $stmt->bind_result($password);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $login_check = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);

                if (hash_equals($login_check, $login_string) ){
                    // Logged In!!!! 
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Not logged in 
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                // Not logged in 
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // Not logged in 
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        // Not logged in 
        return false;
    }
}

function checkUNEmail($uname,$email)
{
    global $mysqli;
    $error = array('status'=>false,'userID'=>0);
    if (isset($email) && trim($email) != '') {
        //email was entered
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare ("SELECT `ID` FROM `users` WHERE `Email` = ? LIMIT 1"))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param('s',trim($email));
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $numRows = $stmt->num_rows();
            $stmt->bind_result($userID);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->close();
            if ($numRows >= 1) return array('status'=>true,'userID'=>$userID);
        } else { return $error; }
    } elseif (isset($uname) && trim($uname) != '') {
        //username was entered
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `ID` FROM `users` WHERE Username = ? LIMIT 1"))
        {
             $stmt->bind_param('s',trim($uname));
             $stmt->execute();
             $stmt->store_result();
            $numRows =  $stmt->num_rows();
             $stmt->bind_result($userID);
             $stmt->fetch();
             $stmt->close();
            if ($numRows >= 1) return array('status'=>true,'userID'=>$userID);
        } else { return $error; }
    } else {
        //nothing was entered;
        return $error;
    }
}



function sendPasswordEmail($userID)
{
    global $mysqli;
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `Username`,`Email`,`Password` FROM `users` WHERE `ID` = ? LIMIT 1"))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('i',$userID);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($uname,$email,$pword);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
        $expFormat = mktime(date("H"), date("i"), date("s"), date("m")  , date("d")+3, date("Y"));
        $expDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$expFormat);
        $key = md5($uname . '_' . $email . rand(0,10000) .$expDate . PW_SALT);
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `recoveryemails_enc` (`UserID`,`Key`,`expDate`) VALUES (?,?,?)"))
        {
             $stmt->bind_param('iss',$userID,$key,$expDate);
            $stmt->execute();
             $stmt->close();
            $passwordLink = "<a href=\"?a=recover&email=" . $key . "&u=" . urlencode(base64_encode($userID)) . "\">http://www.oursite.com/forgotPass.php?a=recover&email=" . $key . "&u=" . urlencode(base64_encode($userID)) . "</a>";
            $message = "Dear $uname,\r\n";
            $message .= "Please visit the following link to reset your password:\r\n";
            $message .= "-----------------------\r\n";
            $message .= "$passwordLink\r\n";
            $message .= "-----------------------\r\n";
            $message .= "Please be sure to copy the entire link into your browser. The link will expire after 3 days for security reasons.\r\n\r\n";
            $message .= "If you did not request this forgotten password email, no action is needed, your password will not be reset as long as the link above is not visited. However, you may want to log into your account and change your security password and answer, as someone may have guessed it.\r\n\r\n";
            $message .= "Thanks,\r\n";
            $message .= "-- Our site team";
            $headers = '';
            $headers .= "From: Our Site <webmaster@oursite.com> \n";
            $headers .= "To-Sender: \n";
            $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP\n"; // mailer
            $headers .= "Reply-To: webmaster@oursite.com\n"; // Reply address
            $headers .= "Return-Path: webmaster@oursite.com\n"; //Return Path for errors
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"; //Enc-type
            $subject = "Your Lost Password";
            @mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers);
            return str_replace("\r\n","<br/ >",$message);
        }
    }
}

function checkEmailKey($key,$userID)
{
     global $mysqli;
    $curDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `UserID` FROM `recoveryemails_enc` WHERE `Key` = ? AND `UserID` = ? AND `expDate` >= ?"))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('sis',$key,$userID,$curDate);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $numRows = $stmt->num_rows();
        $stmt->bind_result($userID);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
        if ($numRows > 0 && $userID != '')
        {
            return array('status'=>true,'userID'=>$userID);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function updateUserPassword($userID,$password,$key)
{
     global $mysqli;
    if (checkEmailKey($key,$userID) === false) return false;
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `Password` = ? WHERE `ID` = ?"))
    {
         $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $stmt->bind_param('si',$password,$userID);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM `recoveryemails_enc` WHERE `Key` = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$key);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}

function getUserName($userID)
{
    global $mysqli;
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `Username` FROM `users` WHERE `ID` = ?"))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('i',$userID);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($uname);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
    }
    return $uname;
}
```

The code to creat the pass on the registration process

```
// Create hashed password using the password_hash function.
        // This function salts it with a random salt and can be verified with
        // the password_verify function.
        $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        // Insert the new user into the database 
        if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $email, $password);
```

Comment: might you reduce this to a small question rather than create a massive code review?  try to boil down the problem to a handful of lines of code if you can.  that might even help you figure out what's going on in the process.

Comment: I delete all the code not needed. I think the problem is in the way the new password is created. Is hashed but maybe not in the right way

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I've discovered the issue. I believe this line requires your attention:

```
$login_check = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);
```

You actually created a hash using [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and BCRYPT so I don't think creating a sha512 hash and comparing it is going to get you very far.  The proper way to verify a hash created with password_hash is with password_verify.  See this example [from the PHP documentation on password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

```
if (password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', $hash)) {
  echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
  echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

And note that

> password_hash() returns the algorithm, cost and salt as part of the returned hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included in it. This allows the verify function to verify the hash without needing separate storage for the salt or algorithm information.

**before and after registration and pw update**

```
$password = '<PUT PASSWORD OF NEW USER HERE>';
$query = 'select password hash from users where id = <PUT ID OF NEW USER HERE>';
$res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
echo $row['hash'].' '.((password_verify($password, $row['hash']))?'hash is good!':'no, no match on hash').'<br>';
```

check after registration to be sure the hash is good, then check after updating the password.

Comment: But i´m using a password verifieng  if (password_verify($password, $db_password)) {...   And the system works well for the registed user, just when the password is changed with the forgotpass, some problem happens

Comment: okay, can you call out the lines of code (should just be three or four) that set the user password during registration so we can compare them to your forgot sequence?

Comment: Thnak you for your time. I post the code on the question above

Comment: They are diferent... what could be the problem?

Comment: I used this tutorial to creat my login system http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Comment: How can i substitute this parts hash('sha512' and hash_equals($login_check? To test if some other thing works for both cases

Comment: first, what i meant by seeing if they are the same was semantically incorrect.  take the "test" code i have added and run it before and after the registration and pw update.

Comment: I´m sorry. Where sould i put that code to teste it?

Comment: Can you take a look at this code used to submite the password input in the registration                                                                                               var p = document.createElement("input");
 
    // Add the new element to our form. 
    form.appendChild(p);
    p.name = "p";
    p.type = "hidden";
    p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);                                                  Maybe that´s why the use of hash('sha512' and hash_equals($login_check?

Comment: so you're hashing it client side in jquery?  you need to not do that unless you will be using a different method to test the hash.  also, the industry standard is to only accept user/pass forms over ssl, so, that removes any necessity to hide that password during the transmission from client side to server side, since the ssl will encrypt it anyway.  but you must receive that raw password for password_hash to properly insert it for password_verify to properly test it.

Comment: Is not permited to use the hashing on the client side? If you can tell me what to do next... I am a litte bit lost.  I don´t want to change all my login system

Comment: permitted?  you can do whatever you want, but if you only send a hash from javascript to php then php won't be able to make a hash...you already did - but you're not using the javascript hash for testing, that's why things aren't matching.  what i'm telling you to do is only use one form of hashing.  right now you are using two.  pick one and only use that.

Comment: just a note, but a hash is not the password.  it's like a key, or more properly a half a key.  and that half a key is stored in the db.  now, there is no way to make the password from that half-a-key hash.  so how do you verify?  you take the real password (from the user login form) and you make another half-a-key (hash) - if your two hashes match, then the password they entered is valid.  perhaps it's this misunderstanding that is confusing things.

Comment: So i want to go the easy way. I will use the one on the registration/login system. What do i have to change on my forgotpass system?

Comment: you need to stop hashing the pw in javascript and send the raw password back to php.  then in php you need to be sure to use password_hash() to put it in the db and not that hash(sha512) stuff.

Comment: But that way i have to change a lot in my login system. There is a way to hash the update password the same way? Isn´t that easier? I´m a begginer i don´t know if i can change my login system

Comment: my friend, if you have a house and install 110 outlets in half the house and 220 outlets in half the house but your system is 110, there is nothing you can do but get rid of the 220 outllets.  you could change the house to 220, but then you'd still have to get rid of the 110 outlets.  i hope you're following here.

Comment: What i m asking is if is possible to change the forgotpass system to javascript hashing. This would solve the problem right?

Comment: Your forgotpass system will have to match your registration system. If registration uses password_hash/verify, then I don't see how you're going to use client side hashing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @WEBjuju. I´m trying to use the same system used to the registration on the forgotpass. But for now i couldn´t make it work